# haml new tr every 3 items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following code (simplified to get to the point):

```
    - @assumptions[1].each do |ca|
      - if count % 3 == 1
        %tr
          %th
            = ca.value
      - else
        %th
          = ca.value
      - count = count + 1
```

I am not sure how to make this work in haml to have every 4 items create a new  tag.

This is how it is outputting:

```
  <tr>
    <tr> 
      <th> 
        700.0
      </th> 
    </tr> 
    <th> 
      1235.0
    </th> 
    <th> 
      0.8
    </th> 
    <th> 
      650.0
    </th> 
  <tr> 
    <th> 
      1050.0
    </th> 
  </tr> 
  <th> 
    0.2
  </th> 
</tr>
```

This is how I would like it to output:

```
<tr>
  <th>
    700.0
  </th>
  <th>
    1235.0
  </th>
  <th>
    0.8
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>
    650.0
  </th>
  <th>
    1050.0
  </th>
</tr>
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable's `each_slice` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001514) to group these into chunks of 3:

```
- @assumptions[1].each_slice(3) do |group|
  %tr
    - group.each do |ca|
      %th= ca.value
```

Comment: Answers like this reaffirm the reason I love Stack Overflow. I just trimmed 20 lines of code (plus a partial) down to 8 (and removed the partial) thanks to this gem of an answer :-)

Comment: This is the beauty of functional programming

Comment: Ruby, I love you. I propose you to be with me for the rest of my programming life.